# TFS2012 CheckinException

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have an issue using Builds i keep getting this error:

```
 Exception Message: TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again. (type CheckinException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.ReportCheckInConflictsFailuresAndThrow(Workspace workspace, CheckinResult checkinResult, Failure[] conflicts, Failure[] failures, Boolean noAutoResolve, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckInInternal(WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn(WorkspaceCheckInParameters checkinParameters)
   at TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities.CheckInFiles.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) in c:\Builds\4_2\BuildAndDeploy\BuildAndDeploy\Sources\tfsversioning\TfsBuild.Versioning.Activities\CheckInFiles.cs:line 55
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

But the problem is that i haven't any conflicts ore checked anything in. The build was triggered, because of an other project. An solution is to run the build again and it passes. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the build process is making changes to source on the build server when it runs. Does your build workflow have any customisations that check out / modify files as part of your build process?

If the same files are changed on another build agent, or by a developer in their local workspace then you'll see conflicts. This is most likely to happen if you have 2 builds running concurrently (i.e. you have 2 build agents and 2 builds are started at the same time)

Some versioning extensions to TFS have this problem because they checkout / modify / checkin and versioning file as part of the build.

In this scenario. the problem would go away when you run another build because the original build that had the pending changes would have finished.